# Antonym for "challenge" (noun form)

Tags: antonyms

I was writing a market research report the other day and listed the **challenges** my company faced in the market in question, then I created a new section header for the... uhh... **easy bits**?

That's when I realized I could think of no reasonable antonym for challenge in the noun form. I can certainly describe it -- *characteristics of the market that will be of benefit to our entry*

"Advantages" is close to the mark but doesn't quite capture the idea because I feel that is in reference to our company, rather than in reference to the market itself.

To give an example:

```
Challenges
  > customer purchasing power is low
  > public perception of our manufacturing location is negative

(Easy Bits / Cakewalks / Happy Things / etc.)
  > no competitive product on the market
  > strong transportation network with low logistical costs
```

"Incentives" also seems close, but not quite there.

Any ideas?

Comment: The challenges are challenges faced by your company. The "other things" are advantages which your company has. They don't relate to the market in general. What am I missing here?

Comment: @AndrewLeach - the opposite of advantage is disadvantage. Both are from the perspective of our company. I'm looking for a slightly different feel, something like "inducements" I guess... Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding the words involved. This is also possible.

Comment: Since this is biztalk, the antonym of _challenge_ for market research purposes would be _merely difficult_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'comparative advantage' is an economic term coined by David Ricardo and underpins the Theory of Free Trade'. An 'absolute advantage' is enjoyed by a country, firm or individual if that entity can produce goods in every area of economic activity with greater efficiency than its competitors. A country, firm or individual enjoys a 'comparative advantage' if it can produce goods more efficiently in certain select economic areas where its competitors can't. (The Economist)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how helpful this is, and you've probably already thought about this, but to me it looks like you're putting together a kind of SWOT analysis (Strengths, Weaknesses, Opportunities and Threats), in which case the "easy bits" would be a combination of the "opportunities" available to your company and "strengths" your company posesses. In the same vein, the "challenges" would be a combination of the "weaknesses" your company has and the "threats" it faces.

Answer (score 1):

From @Matt's SWOT suggestion, ***"strength"*** is probably the best choice because the opposite of strength is weakness and a "challenge" can be considered a less negative way of saying weakness (IMO).  ***"Opportunity"*** isn't a good choice because it is based on something that does not yet exist but has potential.

Answer (score 0):

How about "victories". Challenges, when met, overcome, or transformed, are definitely victories.